# SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException in android While Performing lot of operation at same time and App hangs

Tags: android, database, performance, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am creating an application which works on UDP and MQTT Communication.
When there in background service, lot of data receives from another device in UDP communication at same time and each data is stored to SQLite Database and having lot of operations on Database for different tables in database.

While there are many operations it continues to show error

`SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException at SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();`

and app gets hanged and crashes the app showing message "Unfortunately App has stopped".

So I need a solution to improve this and avoiding this error.

Even I have put every operation in `try..catch...` block but it throws error too.

and Logcat for error is

`05-18 10:34:23.402 1253-1253/com.nivida.smartnode E/SQLiteLog: (14) cannot open file at line 30052 of [b3bb660af9]
05-18 10:34:23.402 1253-1253/com.nivida.smartnode E/SQLiteLog: (14) os_unix.c:30052: (24) open(/storage/emulated/0/Smartnode/smartnodedb.db) - 
05-18 10:34:23.411 1253-1253/com.nivida.smartnode E/SQLiteDatabase: Failed to open database '/storage/emulated/0/Smartnode/smartnodedb.db'.                                                              android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14): Could not open database
                                                                        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeOpen(Native Method)
                                                                        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:209)
                                                                        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:193)
                                                                        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:463)
                                                                        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:185)
                                                                        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:177)
                                                                        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openInner(SQLiteDatabase.java:806)
                                                                        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.open(SQLiteDatabase.java:791)
                                                                        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:694)
                                                                        at android.app.ContextImpl.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextImpl.java:1190)
                                                                        at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:274)
                                                                        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:223)                                                                   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:163)                                                                    at com.nivida.smartnode.model.DatabaseHandler.setDimmerValue(DatabaseHandler.java:1616)`

Comment: post your logcat message